# Как разместить точки на полотне CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, на скриншоте снизу видны оранжевые точки. Как их сверстать? Позиционированием или может лучше объединить с белым полотном, задав тем самым задний фон всему телу сайта?

И еще один вопрос, как реализовать такую нумерацию над параграфами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю

Comment: просто картинкой. но если идея в том, что они должны двигаться, то можно их разбросать абсолютами...или на канвасе нарисовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фон можно сделать и простым фоном.
Если второй вопрос о чёрточках над и под кружочками, то делайте их псевдоэлементами в абсолютном позиционировании, чтобы не было верхней чёрточки у первого элемента используйте :not(), например:

```css
.items {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.item {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item p {
  text-align: center;
}
.item span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.item:not(:first-child) span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.item span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <span>1</span>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur sunt esse quisquam consequuntur! Voluptas sed eaque nobis voluptate, quidem necessitatibus?
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <span>2</span>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur sunt esse quisquam consequuntur! Voluptas sed eaque nobis voluptate, quidem necessitatibus?
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <span>3</span>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur sunt esse quisquam consequuntur! Voluptas sed eaque nobis voluptate, quidem necessitatibus?
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```